# Python Array Copying From Word To Word

Tags: python, arrays, string

So I have an array and I want to copy every string in this array starting where it finds a word I give as a condition and ending in another string that has the same word. For example if I have an array as following:

`['abcde','Loop: atfg','xyzgh','blabla','blablable Loop','other thing']`

I want for example to search for the word loop and copy every string into a new array until it finds loop again. So it should return something as this:

```
['Loop: atfg','xyzgh','blabla','blablable Loop']
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code finds indexes of the first and second elements that contain your `search_str`

```
start_index = my_list.index(next(e for e in my_list if search_str in e))
end_index = my_list.index(next(e for e in my_list[start_index + 1:] if search_str in e))
```

To understand how to use it:

```
my_list = ['trash', 'Loop: 1','2','3','4 Loop', 'more trash']
search_str = "Loop"

start_index = my_list.index(next(e for e in my_list if search_str in e))
end_index = my_list.index(next(e for e in my_list[start_index + 1:] if search_str in e))

result = my_list[start_index:end_index + 1]
```

It might seem a bit weirder than multi-line loops, but it's a bit more Python-way :]

Comment: But what would first_match:index be? because that variable seems to appear out of nowhere. Would it be start_index? UPDATE: I changed it to start_index and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the source list once by yield:

```
i = ['abcde','Loop: atfg','xyzgh','blabla','blablable Loop','other thing']

def find_range(items):
    start = False
    for i in items:
        if 'Loop' in i:
            yield i
            if start:
                break

            start = True
        elif start:
            yield i

print list(find_range(i))
```

Comment: Got a bit confused because of `if start: break`, but otherwise nice :)

Comment: At begin, start is false. when Loop is matched first time, start will be set to true. When Loop is matched again, start is already true, so break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely better ways to handle this, but I think a good old-fashioned loop works best here:

```
def word_copy(lst, search):
    res = []
    for item in lst:
        if res:
            res.append(item)
            if search in item:
                return res

        elif search in item:
            res.append(item)
```

Comment: Note the OPs criteria of *starts with* and *ends with* - not *contains*

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
list = ['abcde','Loop: atfg','xyzgh','blabla','blablable Loop','other thing']
if any("loop" in l for l in list):
```

Comment: This will execute the `if` where the word "loop" appears in any element of the list - how does this help the OPs query?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the list, looking for the first occurrence, then the second occurrence:

```
input = ['abcde','Loop: atfg','xyzgh','blabla','blablable Loop','other thing']
target = 'Loop'

start_index, end_index = None, None
for i in input:
    if target in i:
        if start_index is None:
             start_index = input.index(i)
             continue
        end_index = input.index(i)
        break

output = input[start_index : end_index + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

with your list:

```
list = ['abcde','Loop: atfg','xyzgh','blabla','blablable Loop','other thing']
```

i think you could try doing something like this, in order to find the positions in the array:

```
ixs = [i for i, word in enumerate(list) if word.startswith('Loop') or word.endswith('Loop')]
```

Then you just need slice the list:

```
res = list[ixs[0]:ixs[1]+1]
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are some fancy one-liner solutions. :)
Yet I love brute-force ones that look more understanding:

```
>>> my_list = ['abcde','Loop: atfg','xyzgh','blabla','blablable Loop','other thing']
>>> search_str = "(Loop)+"
>>> out = []
>>> count = 0
>>> for s in my_list:
...     if count == 2:
...         break
...     m = re.search(search_str, s)
...     if m != None:
...         count += 1
...     if count >= 1:
...         out.append(s)
...
>>> out
['Loop: atfg', 'xyzgh', 'blabla', 'blablable Loop']
>>>
```